# want to create a new custom eclipse for pic c builder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, customization, pic

Pic c builder is a plugin for eclipse that already available

We are trying to create a new IDE with eclipse base and also with the Pic c builder

Specs

Own launcher not the original eclipse splash screen
Custom IDE Name
Custom Project Type as PIC C Builder

Give me the suggestion where can i find the detailed information about this topics

---

Not only the Splash screen

i want to change the entire eclipse to My Custom Name

[image]

Change the IDE name

[image]

And About Eclipse Details

I think it's doable

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna just change Splash Screen from Eclipse, browse to your Eclipse directory: `/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_X.Y.Z.vXYZXYZXYXZYXZYXZ/` and replace `splash.bmp` with your new one.